# How to search and replace newline using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

To be more specific, I am trying to achieve this.

For example:

```
Hello. Welcome to stackoverflow!




This is for testing purpose only.

So let's get started!

Good job. See you tomorrow.
```

and I want to remove ONE newline each. So the result should be:

```
Hello. Welcome to stackoverflow!



This is for testing purpose only.
So let's get started!
Good job. See you tomorrow.
```

but if I search it using `\n\n` regex and replace all with `\n`, the result is:

```
Hello. Welcome to stackoverflow!


This is for testing purpose only.
So let's get started!
Good job. See you tomorrow.
```

the problem is there're two results that matches that regex between Hello... and ...This so it replace twice there.

What I want done is, I just want to remove ONE line for each, no matter how many lines there are.

Wow should I achieve this?

Comment: How newlines are handled and matched depends on which regex implementation you are using. Some purely line-oriented regex tools simply cannot match a newline. Please review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag guidance](/tags/regex/info) and add suitable platform or language tag(s) in accordance with that.

Comment: oh, I will look into it. I am not sure which, notepad ++ is my primary editor though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookbehind:

```
(?<=\.|!)\n
```

and replace by nothing. That will remove just the one `\n` that follows `.` or `!`.

Alternatively you can also use lookahead:

```
\n(?=\w)
```

This matches any one `\n` that is followed by a letter, a number or an underscore.

Comment: oh gee, the second one is much better because I don't know what the sentence would end with :)  thx but I guess \n\n(?=\w) is more proper regex and replace with \n.

Comment: because some setence would just have one newline and it would mess up the phrasal structure of the text.

Comment: You can also try
^\s*(\n)
with $1 as replacement (works with Notepad++)

Comment: So if my answer helps you please consider accepting and/or upvoting it

Answer (score 0):

Either delete all:

```
(?<!\n)\n
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Mm1nTTD123gTkg).

*Or* if your tool/language doesn't support look-behinds, replace all:

```
([^\n])\n
```

with captured group 1, which is `$1` or `\1` depending on your tool/language.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(\R+)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(\R+)       # group 1, 1 or more linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]